# Multiple Browser using java SWT.MOZILLA and XULRunner

Tags: java, browser, swt, xulrunner

This is my First post on this site. I hope, i would get help very soon and would be able to help others.

I am trying to open multiple browser (with different or same urls) at the same time (like pop ups) and getting them close after few seconds in the same order they were opened. I assumed, I need to use multi-threading to do it or can I use Eclipse Job API for this?

**My Problem here:** I wrote below code to open multiple browsers but it open up second browser after it closes the first one. I want to open up the second browser while the first one stay open and close the first one after specified seconds.

I am using SWT-4.4-win32-win32-x86, XULRunner-3.6.28.en-US.win32 on windows 7 with jdk1.8.0_20_32 and Eclipse Luna 4.4.1. Please let me know if you need any other information to assist me.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.ProgressEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.ProgressListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;


public class NestedThread extends Thread{

    public static boolean loaded = false;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String xulrunnerDir = "C:\\XULRunner\\xulrunner3628";
        System.setProperty("org.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath", xulrunnerDir);

        String[] urlList = { "http://google.com","http://ipchicken.com"};

        final Display display = Display.getDefault();

        for (String url : urlList) {
            createwindow(display, url);             
        }
    }

      public static void  createwindow(Display display, String url){

            Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {
              public void run() { 
                  System.out.println("inside run");
                  loaded = false;
                    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);  
                    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
                    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
                    Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.MOZILLA);
                    browser.setUrl(url);
                    shell.open();

                    browser.addProgressListener(new ProgressListener() {

                        public void changed(ProgressEvent event)
                        {
                        }
                        public void completed(ProgressEvent event)
                        {
                            loaded = true;
                            System.out.println("Loaded");
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(3000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            shell.close();

                        }

                       });

                        while (!shell.isDisposed () && !loaded) {  
                          if (!display .readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();  
                        }

              }
            });

      }
}
```

I already spent more than a week to do it. but I failed. Please help. I would really appreciate anyone's help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you could solve the problem by using threads, it isn't necessary. You can use Display-timerExec() to close the browser window with a delay.
Here is one possible solution:

```
public static void main( String args[] ) {
  Display display = new Display();
  createwindow( display, "http://google.com" );
  createwindow( display, "http://ipchicken.com" );
  while( display.getShells().length > 0 ) {
    if( !display.readAndDispatch() ) {
      display.sleep();
    }
  }
  display.dispose();
}

static void createwindow( Display display, String url ) {
  final Shell shell = new Shell( display );
  shell.setLayout( new FillLayout() );
  Browser browser = new Browser( shell, SWT.NONE );
  browser.setUrl( url );
  shell.open();
  browser.addProgressListener( new ProgressAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void completed( ProgressEvent event ) {
      event.display.timerExec( 3000, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          shell.close();
        }
      } );
    }
  } );
}
```

The code opens the browser windows right away one after another and closes each window after a delay of three seconds. This should also work with `SWT.MOZILLA` but I haven't installed a Mozilla runtime and thus cannot verify.

The call to `Display.syncExec()` in `createWindow` was unnecessary as the code runs on the UI thread anyway.

Comment: Thanks Rüdiger Herrmann for your quick response. Your response was really helpful and solved my half of the problem. I needed to use SWT.MOZILLA so I could change the proxy(ip and port) for different browser as SWT.NONE uses only system proxies and I don't know if I can change the system proxies at run time to use it with each new browser. Per my expected result if I open ipchicken.com in two different browser, it should show two different IP. Thanks again in Advance!!

Comment: Hi Rüdiger Herrmann, I am adding another request on this same program. As your program works fine to open multiple browser one after the another. Could you please change your program little bit to open the second browser after previous browser is loaded completely plus the few second of delay. I tried to do it using Multi-threading, but its giving me error of "Exception in thread "Thread-0" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access". Please help! Please let me know if you want me to post as another question for this problem. I hope to hear from you soon!

Comment: @Kanhaiya to open the browser windows one at a time you could _chain_ the open calls. Put the URLs to be opened in a stack and right after `shell.close()` pop a URL from the stack and pass it on to `createWindow()`

Comment: Thanks Rudiger, I need to create window just after my first window is loaded with a small delay(like 2 seconds) while the first window is still waiting to be closed!( like it will be closed after 10 seconds after it's loaded). I really appreciate your responses!!